# Получение переменной из абстрактного класса без вызова функции

Tags: php, ооп

Ребятушки, помогите, пожалуйста. Есть класс `Site`, есть абстрактный класс `SiteBase`. В классе `SiteBase` есть функция `checkCart()`, которая подсчитывает количество товаров в корзине (сделана на сессии). Каким образом сделать так, чтобы при объявлении `Class Site extends SiteBase` в классе `Site` можно было получить количество товаров в корзине, т.е. без вызова определенной функции?

Код абстрактного класса:

```
abstract class SiteBase
{
    public $cartItems;
    /**
     * Return count of items in cart
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function checkCart()
    {
        $cartItems = Cart::getProducts();
        if ($cartItems) {
            $this->cartItems = Cart::countItems();            
        } else {
            $this->cartItems = 0;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Хочется получить, чтобы тут:

```
Class Site extends SiteBase {
    function echoCartItems(){
      $cartItems //чтобы она была доступна
    }
}
```

Comment: так а почему нельзя просто сделать так
$cartItems = $this->cartItems; //чтобы она была доступна

Comment: @ВладимирМикитюк не до конца понял, где именно? Поскольку абстрактные классы не могут вызывать внутри себя функции, сделать это в классе SiteBase нельзя, т.е. сделать в классе Site конструктор, где будет задаваться переменная?

Comment: ну так к примеру
 function echoCartItems(){
  self::checkCart();
  echo $this->cartItems;
 }
  }

Comment: @Alexxosipov ты когда наследуешься, у тебя поля вообще-то тоже наследуются. http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/128d4b5d30e279bfe960308457cf8682ec3782e6 ... поэтому тебе и говорят про `$this->cartItems;`

Comment: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/7d549fd73d19f80ae1c857b20985cd6e9091126e  - так что пока не ясно что у тебя не так